# I am trying to combine a image view and a text view inside of a view pager. Is it possible?

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, android-studio

I would like to have an image on top, the title below it, and also a price tag, all within a ViewPager. The image below is what I want in my project. I am using multiple arrays, one which stores the image URL, one which stores the title, and one which stores the price. Is there an easy way of doing this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkkDc.jpg)

Comment: your use case is really similar to implementing a on boarding screen try doing that by watching some youtube tutorials with viewpager2 you can also use recyclerview and i would recommend using databinding for your use case after creating an object of your requirement the easy way here can also be to implement a third party library that does exactly this although none i know of does it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's better to create an array of objects (name it for example StockItem). Then you should create an adapter for ViewPager. Set array of StockItems to this adapter. Also, you should create a layout for viewpager element (which contains Linear vertical layout for example with image, title and price) and then bind this view holder with StockItem

Comment: I will try and implement this now and see how it goes. But thanks, much appreciated